# How to draw over other apps with the iOS SDK

Tags: ios

Android has a permission that allows apps to "draw over other apps" with floating content (using the S`YSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission). Does iOS have anything similar?

Comment: Local notifications may be what you want.

Comment: I'm interested in drawing a shape (ie handwriting annotation) over the screen, instead of an actual notification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this can't be done. A user can only interact with whatever app is currently in the foreground.

Comment: I see google meet draws the widget over the app when we go in the background and any meeting is ongoing.

Comment: Is this answer still correct in 2023 with iOS 16/17?